# Can the active player receive free cards in Bohnanza?

Tags: bohnanza

The rules state that you can give a player free cards, if both players agree.

Does this mean that the other players can offer free cards to the active player, (in order to get rid of them).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but (as you note) the donations need not be accepted.

From the rulebook, page 5:

> Although trading is preferable to donating, it is often in a player’s
>   interest to donate cards rather than keeping them, since cards kept
>   must eventually be planted. The active player may donate the two face
>   up cards he drew or cards from his hand. The other players may only
>   donate cards to the active player and from their hands. Donations
>   need not be accepted.

Comment: Depending on how desperate the offering player is (or seems to be), it is not to unusual to hear nasty questions like *what other card(s) do you give me as a payment for accepting your donation?*

Comment: (Probably intended as a comment to the OP's question, as the comment doesn't seem to be about this answer in particular outside of the question)

Comment: It was intended as a comment to this answer, because **the answer points out that the donation may be refused**, that's why the one to whom the donation was offered has the power to declare *accepting* the donation his service-part of the deal and to ask for a payment.